# How can I show the text on a ImageButton?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to create this type of layout for my app can someone help me . How can i create this type of layout.?

[Layout screen shot ,please check it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apljl.png)

Comment: use FrameLayout. an image on back and a button on top. set button clickable : false so your image will receive the click

Answer (score 1):

For a button this too works pretty fine. Putting android:background is fine!

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/fragment_left_menu_login"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
android:text="@string/login_string" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/images"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/style"
            android:text="Pasta"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/images"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/style"
            android:text="Pasta"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/images"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/style"
            android:text="Pasta"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

create an style file in your drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="7dp" />

    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#55ffffff"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: thank you so much it is working but how can i add space between images.?

Comment: you can increase android:layout_marginTop of each LinearLayout.

Comment: if my response answered your question, I would be glad if you accept my response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MaterialButton for this case.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="Non vegetarian"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_btn"
    app:backgroundTint="@drawable/bg_rounded_btn" />
```

@drawable/bg_rounded_btn file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

       <corners android:radius="10dp" />

       // In your case color transparent
       <solid android:color="@color/white" />

       // In your case color white
       <stroke
           android:width="1dp"
           android:color="@color/scooter_dark" />

   </shape>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIBEJ.png)